# How to record video in iphone

Tags: iphone

HI,

I need to record video using iPhone. To do that i used UIImagePickerController. I have an iPhone 3G, with me. when i run my code to check if source type available it says device not supported. My OS is 3.2.1, where i am wrong, can some one tell me what i need to change.

Also is there some other way to record video. What i need to do is to get the video stream as it is recorded.

```
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;

NSArray *sourceTypes = 
[UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:picker.sourceType];
if (![sourceTypes containsObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeVideo ]){
    NSLog(@"device not supported");
    return;
}

//picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;    
picker.mediaTypes =  [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeVideo];    
picker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;


[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

That is because the 3G isn't supported for video recording.

Comment: Please flag this as the correct answer: this place is give and take.

Comment: there are apps like iCamcorder which records video on iPhone 3G, and I know they did something, so this isnt correct answer.

Comment: hmmm - if indeed they are able to utilise the same frameworks for video recording - see the WWDC2010 vids free on iTunes to developers for video recording - an active working example is available.

Answer (score 1):

Lance is correct. The native UIImagePickerController does not work on iPhone 3G. If an app does do video recording on a 3G they are doing a hack like taking multiple photos in succession and manually encoding a video file using the individual images.